# Please explain colons within optional arguments and optarg as seen in the code below

Tags: c, getopt

All of the code below makes sense with the exception of how it is that colons are being used and optarg function as seen under case 's' and 'f'. I've attempted to google what exactly each means but I get lost in the jungle of computer science language that confuses me.

```
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "Ss:f:")) != -1) { //ask about colons in office hours

        switch (c) 
        {
        case 'S':
            should_print_file_size = 1;
            break;
        case 's':
            min_file_size = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'f':
            substring = optarg;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Please only use S, s, or f arguments.");
            return -1;

        }
    }
```

Please help!

Comment: [getopt manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt): "*If such a character is followed by a colon, the option requires an argument*". So in the example code `-S` does not require an arg but `-s` and `-f` do. Does that help?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by it requires an argument. What argument? Where? How?

Comment: "Requires an argument" means "you must pass a value to the option". So `s:` means that on the command line, `-s` must be followed by some value. With your getopt string, `mycommand -S -s foo` is a valid command line, but `mycommand -S -s` is not, because there is no argument to the `-s` option.

Comment: When you run your program you can pass it args as specified to `getopt`. So running `./my_program -S` will work as `-S` does not require an arg. But `./my_program -f` will fail because `-f` requires an arg and needs to be run like `./my_program -f blah`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean this `getopt` in the while:

```c++
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "Ss:f:")) != -1)
```

As @Kaylum pointed out in the comments, the [getopt manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) states the following syntax:

```c++
int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[],
           const char *optstring);
```

Where `optstring` argument is described as:

> optstring is a string containing the legitimate option characters. If
> such a character is followed by a colon, the option requires an
> argument, so getopt() places a pointer to the following text in the
> same argv-element, or the text of the following argv-element, in
> optarg

So you can see in the following two cases for `s` and `f`:

```
        case 's':
            min_file_size = atoi(optarg);    // <--- case 's' Takes optarg
            break;
        case 'f':
            substring = optarg;              // <--- case'f' takes optarg
            break;
```

and from the while you have `s:` and `f:`. So imagine it being stated as something like this:
`s: <argument>` and `f: <argument>`